# How is blockchain hiding its HTML source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, blockchain

When you navigate to: [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/wallet/#/login)

You will notice that if you click `view-source` on the page, it will show HTML context different than that when you `inspect-element`. My question is, how are they doing this?

I understand they are using `.pug` templates from AngularJS framework. But how does my browser know where to read them from if they are not loaded from the client-(browser)-side?

Also, if I was to insert jQuery onto the page, would the jQuery know when the events are triggered `on('click', 'submit', 'whatever') etc ...`?

Comment: They are doing it with Javascript. Research the concept of a single page app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click `View Source`, you see what the server sends back. Many pages do not send back a full HTML page, instead some skeleton HTML and add the rest of the functionality via JavaScript

When you `Inspect Element`, you're viewing the browser's representation of the DOM, which includes any manipulations done via JavaScript. For a visual explanation, see this article on css-tricks: https://css-tricks.com/dom/

Comment: What about my second question, if I go about inserting code that will ask the user to complete a survey in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of the server-side loaded page. Will my jQuery code also pick up on the elements added to the DOM after the browser displays it?

Comment: Sure, just make sure it's the last script loaded and the other JavaScript code has finished running before yours starts

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Any framework that is rendering HTML client-side (React, Angular, Vue) will do that. The actual source code could literally just be some basic html boilerplate and a div that then gets loaded with an application through something like Javascript. Thus, when you view the source of the page, you're seeing this basic templating. But when inspecting an element, Chrome Dev tools (and others) are inspecting the element that is being rendered client side. Your browser has placed those elements on the DOM, they didn't exist in the source code till the code executed. Hope that helps clear things up.